If Miles doesn’t consider Peter’s actions as hacking, then what does he think Peter is doing to the computer?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Peter Parker and Miles Morales are on the way to the Super-collider:

Peter: Step One: I infiltrate the lab. Two: Find the head scientist's
computer.
Miles: That lady with the bike is the head scientist. I saw her in
this  documentary.
PETER: Cool! Step Three: I reexamine my personal biases. Step Four: I
hack the computer.
Miles: It's not technically hacking.

If Miles doesn’t consider Peter’s actions as hacking, then what does he think Peter is doing to the computer?

Social engineering.

Peter's plan was, evidently, to shadow the Head Scientist until he can use her computer to access her files. He refers to this as 'hacking' her computer.

Miles POPS into the multi-panel image of Peter downloading the override code from the scientist’s computer--
MILES: --It’s not technically hacking. It’s kinda--
PETER: (shoves him out) --Not now hold on, I just lost my train of thought... Step Five: download the important stuff, I’ll know it when I see it, and Step Six:... I grab a bagel from the cafeteria and run.

Miles, somewhat sniffily, observes that he doesn't consider having physical access to a computer (or worse, 'shoulder surfing', yuk) to be what he would consider proper hacking.

BELOW THE VENTS, the Head Scientist leads Kingpin to a computer--
HEAD SCIENTIST: Look at this data. I know you can’t really understand it, but
these are really good numbers
INT. LAB - CONTINUOUS
She goes to the computer and enters her password.
PETER: And... I got the password!
Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse Screenplay


shoulder what ? This is too much for kids movie.

But Miles, when making this observation as they construe their plan, doesn't know that Peter will do this: Peter only points out he will "find the head scientist's computer", and then 'hack' it.

@Joachim - Miles can see Peter's comicbook-style panels. It's a fun little bit of fourth wall breaking.

But those panels don't show Peter gleaning the password - they just show him seeing the head scientist, and then switching to him 'hacking' a computer.

@Joachim - The script doesn't always match perfectly with what's on screen. Sometimes the magic of the movies is that the director does something the writer didn't intend.

I get how movies work, but the question is about an in-universe explanation, which I believe my answer more aptly provides than yours. But I see the script indeed corroborates your answer, so I'll withdraw my downvote.

@HaoLano "This is too much for kids movie" Back in my day...

It is a computer nerd joke.
“Hacking” just means using a computer really well to do cool stuff — at least to the people who invented the term. ESR (yes, the Eric S Raymond) has a whole section about it in his well-known Jargon File, which any programmer worth his salt considers to be basic, introductory level reading.
Breaking into another person’s computer, even by just shoulder-surfing a password, is not hacking, it is cracking. (Again, see the Jargon File.)
However, modern media (since at least as far back as the ’90s) has, as usual, totally misunderstood the difference between the terms, in large part because crackers (especially script-kiddies who really do not have the education and understanding of actual computer scientists) do not like the term and prefer to think of themselves as cool hackers, just because they can abuse their tools better than Mom and Pop think possible. (Complete with movies of exactly that. Think: War Games and Hackers.)
There has always been some pushback from actual computer programmers against the pejorative (and wrong!) use of the term “hacker” — some of which makes it into modern media, particularly media people studying computer science have access to. Assuming Miles is actually studying some CS, and appears to be competent on his computer (even if he doesn’t know how to make his own “goober”), it seems reasonable to me that he would have at least a vague idea of the difference, if not simply know that it is wrong.
Either that or it is just a joke meant for us viewers, like the in-universe joke where Miles and Genke watch Spider-Man: The Motion Picture (that they starred in) and protect the real Spiderman’s identity (see this question).

So to revisit our scene: Peter B uses the term “hack” with his usual careless aplomb, to which Miles, still unsure about his “janky old broke hobo Spiderman”, responds by saying, essentially, that Peter’s deficient vocabulary is not inspiring any more confidence now that they’re actually engaging with dangerous people.

Say, is Eric S. Raymond supposed to be someone I should know? I'm feeling curious now.

For computer nerds, he is someone you have likely heard about, at least. Clicky-clicky!

I may be a software engineer, I never heard his name x) I feel like I'm missing something.

You haven’t. Some of his thoughts have been important to the open-source movement, plus he maintains the Jargon File, and he has a number of other views about things that make him more or less (in)famous. That’s all.

(That, and the world of SE is significantly larger now than it was in the late ’90s.)

ESR is known for the Cathedral and the Bazaar, the Jargon File and Fetchmail.

...all of this information about him is in the Wikipedia article I conveniently linked for y’all.

Cracking a password is to repeatedly guess it until you're right. Just watching someone type it in so that you know it is neither cracking nor hacking.

@OrangeDog So brute forcing is a form of cracking?

Any effort to break security is cracking. That technically includes both shoulder-surfing and brute-force attacks. The Jargon file goes into this in detail. Lots of clicky!

This is pure semantics, an illustration of Miles' urge to prove himself capable, and another nod to a stereotypical movie device (like how Peter B. refers to the USB flash drive as a "goober").
'Hacking' can be defined as "the use of unconventional or illicit means to gain unauthorized access to a digital device, computer system or computer network".1
As Peter initially narrates his plan to Miles, there is no sign of him observing the head scientist logging in and remembering the password (it would even make for a weak plan, as they can't know the head scientist is present or will log in during their infiltration). Miles points out that "it's not technically hacking", because Peter evidently requires physical access to that computer. He (in all likelihood) won't technically access it in any unauthorized way (if you can log in, you are authorized), and won't actually be hacking the computer.
This is only evidenced by Peter later on watching Olivia Octavius logging in and remembering the password (and telling Miles to remember it, after he shows he can turn invisible).

1: https://www.ibm.com/topics/cyber-hacking

Side note: logging in using stolen credentials is absolutely unauthorized access.  But that nevertheless does seem to be the distinction that Miles is drawing.

@JohnBollinger I had been struggling with that distinction, too, but figured that from the "point of view" of the computer/OS/system, using proper credentials gives one authorized access. But obviously 'authorization' can be seen from both sides of the equation.
